# Why fonts are cutten above the "ascender" line on a Qt application running on embedded linux?

Tags: linux, qt, fonts, embedded, embedded-linux

UPDATE
After other tests i verified that this issue below is related to some problem in the rendering of the font.
So in the end i chose a simpler solution: i edited the font moving the "ascender" line upper in a way that now all the symbols are under this line. And now i can see alle the symbols correctly!

===========================================================================

I have some problems to correctly visualize the font Helvetica Neue LT Std Font on an embedded device. The problem is that i can't see the part of a character that is in the ascender area of the font, for example i can't see the accent of the char "À". But also for example the symbol ^ above the char "ê" is cutten. Checking the font with fontdrop.info i can confirm that the parts of the characters that are cutten are the parts in the ascender area.

If i run the application on PC, it works fine.
My embedded device is based on a iMx6 ULL processor. The screen resolution is 800x480.

Meaning of "ascender area"
[image]

I verified that the font that is displayed is the correct one. I tried to edit the font moving the symbol above the "À" under the "ascender" line and in this way the symbol is visible. So i can confirm that the problem is in the visualization of the symbols or of the parts of a character that is in the ascender area.

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QFont>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QFont font("HelveticaNeueLTStd");
//    font.setStretch(QFont::Condensed);
    app.setFont(font);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 480
//    FontLoader { id: fixedFont; name: "HelveticaNeueLTStd" }

    Text {
        id: textEdit
        text: qsTr("212Àê\u222B")
        font.pointSize: 24
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.topMargin: 20
//        font.family: fixedFont.name
    }
}
```

PC vs Embedded example
[image]

Maybe is not a Qt problem but is a problem in some configuration of fonts management on my embedded system? Please Help!